# On Mac OS X terminal, how can cd to a folder, which contains space between characters?

Tags: macos, directory, subdirectory

I couldn't go to the folder python 2.7 ,when types cd Python 2.7 on mac terminal , it not works because of empty space between "python" and "2.7", so how can I do cd Python 2.7 on Mac terminal

Comment: Very simple way to go to any kind of folder name , go to the specific folder through Finder then drag that folder into Terminal

Answer (score 0):

`cd "python 2.7"` perhaps (else 2.7 is read as a second parameter of the cd command)

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the directory name in single quotes, or double quotes, or put a backslash before the space.

```
cd python\ 2.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type the beginning of the command in the parent folder:

```
cd pyth
```

and press Tab for the autocompletion to finish the job automatically:

```
cd python\ 2.7/
```

This method is very handy for weird paths (e.g. with spaces, newlines or UTF-8 chars).